# Adding 2 queries from 2 php files together

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm working on an android app where I'm supposed to create one recipe including its picture. I have one php file called `create_recipe.php`, in that file I'm creating the title, ingredients, description and category - all these values are created in a single query. Also, I have a second php file called `UploadImage.php` to pick a photo from the gallery or from the camera and upload it to the web server, and this is done in a single query as well. In my java code I'm calling `create_recipe.php` first and then `UploadImage.php`. Doing it like this will save the information in a different rows.

Is there any way to make this query in a single row in the DB? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code for `UploadImage.php`

```
<?php

$target_path    =   "./images".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$pic            =   ($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$file_path      =   $_FILES['tmp_name'];

// include db connect class
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/android_connect/db_connect.php');

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    // Make your database insert only if successful and insert $target_path, not $file_path
    // Use mysqli_ or PDO with prepared statements

    // here I'm making the query to add the image
    $result =   mysql_query("INSERT INTO scb( name) VALUES('$target_path')");
} else
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";

?>;
```

Here is my code for `create_recipe.php`

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new recipe row
 * All recipe details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['title']) 
    && isset($_POST['ingredients']) 
    && isset($_POST['description'])
    && isset($_POST['category']) ) {
//  && isset($_POST['image'])

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    // include db connect class
    define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once(__ROOT__.'/android_connect/db_connect.php');

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO scb(title, ingredients, description, category, name) VALUES('$title', '$ingredients', '$description', '$category', '$target_path')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Recipe successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple update query will do the trick!

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE scb SET name = '$target_path' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```